# Editing Master Detail Records using Linq-2-Sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I'm using Linq-2-Sql as ORM in asp.net mvc-3 application. First have a look at the form:

[image]

This is a master-detail form for editing batch info. Master part (Batch table) includes BatchNo, SKUTitle, StageID and Date field. Detail part (BatchDetail) contains fields PackingInstruction, ExpectedYield, Units and TargetDate. I have managed to save this information on single page in create scenario like

```
public ActionResult CreateBatch(Batch batch, BatchDetail detail)
{
    batch.BatchDetails.AddRange(detail.ToList());
    ctx.Batches.InsertOnSubmit(batch);
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

but edit scenario is quite tricky. in this form as shown in figure above, user can add new records in detail portion, delete and edit existing records and by the time data is posted to controller we have no way of knowing which records are newly added, which are modified and which are deleted. So, as a consequence I have to do something like

```
public ActionResult EditBatch(int id, BatchDetail detail)
{
     var batch = ctx.Batches.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.BatchID == id);
     ctx.BatchDetails.DeleteAllOnSubmit(ctx.BatchDetails.ToList());
     UpdateModel(batch);
     batch.BatchDetails.AddRange(detail);
     ctx.SubmitChanges();

}
```

I hate that part of deleting detail records in this scenario. is there a way in Linq-2-Sql that I can get around deleting all records in similar scenarios? If not can I accomplish  this in EF without unnecessary deletion?

### Edit

I have been studying Attach method of `System.Data.Linq.Table` but can't seem to figure out anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the MVC Music Store Demo there is a small part that covers deleting items from the shopping cart by using JQuery AJAX to call the delete Controller action. The example is in [part 8 of this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-8).

The actual AJAX call explanation is about 3/4 of the way down the page.  The headline for the section is "Ajax Updates with jQuery" if you want to search and find it quickly.